# PHP shell_exec which mysqld refuses to work

Tags: php, shell

1. I attempt to run the command `echo shell_exec('which mysqld');` in *PHP* which yields *nothing*.
2. I manually go to the *terminal* and run `$ which mysqld` which yields the answer.
3. I run the command `echo shell_exec('whoami');` in PHP which gives me `user`.
4. I go back to the *terminal* and run `$ which mysqld` as the user PHP is running as and get the answer.

How do I force PHP to return `echo shell_exec('which mysqld');` whether it "feels" like it or not?

Yes, the database is running.

Comment: are you testing the CLI with the same user executing php on your webserver?

Comment: @JonathandosSantos Please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like php doesn't know what the executable is, it's possible it doesnt know what the command is (it might not be in your `$PATH`), or it's a shell builtin, you may be better off running a command with `bash -c "which mysql"`, or something of that nature, to force your script to run it in the context of an actual shell session.

Comment: "You can accept this answer in 9 minutes." Thank you! :-)